# Ruby on Rails 3 : Playing with views [2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I already create my web with the main index is in /localhost/store
In the main body, there is a right sidebar with a profile information.

What I want to do is ...
When I browsing to my detail post where the url is /localhost/posts/3, I want to change my right sidebar with another list of the new posting (like similar question on stackoverflow when I type my question). Is there any way I can detect my url (change from store to posts)?

Kindly your help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking exactly, but i think this is what you want to do
In you views, you can detect the current page by using the following:

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => "", :action => "index") %> 
    ....original right sidebar code.......
<% elsif current_page?(:controller => "posts", :action => "show") %>
    ....new right sidebar code.......
<% else %>
    ....do something else.......
<% end %>
```

I am using jquery to this with some ajax on my site(bit more complicated), but i think this might be sufficient for what you are asking. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. this is exactly what I need. 
but there is an error in `:controller => ""`
my store/index is the localhost. what is the controller name for just `localhost`?

Comment: @mamatozay what controller is the index action located in? without seeing any of your code it looks like :controller => "store" will work. Also try current_page?('/') or current_page(root_url) if defined in your config/routes.rb file

Comment: My config for localhost is `root :to => "store#index", :as => 'store'`  
Here is my if branch on the store/index :  
`<% if current_page?(:controller => "store", :action => "index") %> 
  <%= render :partial => "store/footer", :collection => @postsListMainDinamic %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => "store/rightsidebar1", :collection => @postsRightSidebar1 %>
<% end %>`  
But the _footer doesn't load when I in `localhost:3000`  
I am already try `(:controller => "/"` and `(:controller => "root_url"` but this is just give me another error.  
Is my `root :to` on the config wrong?

Comment: My mistake is in the config/routes.rb. I am already change it to `root :to => "store#index"`.   Thanks for your support.  I have another question again.  When I am in localhost:3000, it give me error `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}` when I used `<% if current_page?(:controller => "posts", :action => "show") %>`.  I think when the url like `/localhost/posts/31`, I don't know the `:action` because it is a posts id. Please your help again :)

Comment: @mamatozay sorry for the delay. You could try <% if current_page?(:controller => "posts") %> only. might just work.

Comment: also checkout the api http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F